# Excel lookup previous/above value when value matches

Tags: excel, indexing, lookup

please help me. basically the 2 formulas works separately, but doesn't work when I combine them:

In cell **A2** I have this formula:

=ROW(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7512,MATCH(Sheet3!H2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7512,0)))

*This formula gets matches a value from another sheet and get its row number.*

In cell B2 I have this formula:

=LOOKUP(2,1/(LEFT(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"&**A2**),2)="FA"),INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"&ROW(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7512,MATCH(Sheet3!H2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7512,0)))))

*This formula starts with the range from A2 and finds the last previous value starting with "FA".*

This works fine.

But When I copy/paste A2 into B2, I get **#N/A** (bold part is what I pasted).
=LOOKUP(2,1/(LEFT(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"&**ROW(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7512,MATCH(Sheet3!H2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7512,0)))**),2)="FA"),INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"&ROW(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7512,MATCH(Sheet3!H2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7512,0)))))

Anybody might know whis this happens? Basically I just want to be able to fit everything in 1 formula instead of using 2 columns to get 1 value.

THANK YOU!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWyIr.png)

Comment: Not an answer to your question but wouldn't `ROW(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7512,MATCH(Sheet3!H2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7512,0)))` be simpler as `MATCH(Sheet3!H2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0)`  (assuming you can rule out matches in row1) ?

Comment: INDIRECT doesn't like ROW, you can check that with evaluate. I'm not behind a pc now, but you could try Tim his suggestion eliminating the ROW function, and otherwise you could use CELL function to get the row.

Comment: Nevermind I think I got it to work?! =D =LOOKUP(2,1/(LEFT(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"&MATCH(Sheet3!G2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$7512,0)),2)="FA"),INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:A"&MATCH(Sheet3!G2,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$7512,0)))

Comment: Hi Tim, Yes I think you are right! IT'S PERFECT, THANK YOU!